# How can I know event reach which element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

my html structure like this below:

```
<div onclick='g(e)'>
    <span><button>click me</button></span>
</div>
```

when I click the button tag,the click event will deliver to the div.So my question is when the click event deliver to the span element,if some condition is true,then I can call e.stopPropagation(),and it will not deliver to the div element,the function g wil not run.Would you like to help me?Thanks.

Comment: The pattern you describe of using `stopPropagation` will work. Why can't you write the code for the condition?

Comment: try to show your script for if condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span').click(function(e){if(true){e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault()};});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it but in your case it always come on button

**IN HTML**

```
<div rel="div">
    <span rel="span"><button>click me</button></span>
</div>
```

**in JS**

```
$("button").click(function(e){
   console.log(e.target);
if($(e.target).attr("rel")=="span")
{
e.stopPropagation();
    alert("click on span");
    //f(e);
}
else if($(e.target).attr("rel")=="div"){
alert("click on div");

}
  else{
      alert("click on button");
    }

});
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LArBW/79/)**

or you want to your work then apply click action on **div** in this span ,button and div come
like below

```
$("div").click(function(e){
   console.log(e.target);
if($(e.target).attr("rel")=="span")
{
e.stopPropagation();
    alert("click on span");
    //f(e);
}
else if($(e.target).attr("rel")=="div"){
alert("click on div");

}
  else{
      alert("click on button");
    }

});
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LArBW/80/)**